# Unable to use Google Drive in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL on my computer and I was able to use my Google Drive using WSL till today. I have a soft link to my Drive (/mnt/g/'My Drive') but it is not working now. When I attempt to use this soft link, `-bash: cd: drive: No such file or directory`. When I check the location, I see that there is no files but weird part is that everything seems normal when I use Windows' File Explorer.

What could be the problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS but now it works. I didn't understand why but... Thanks for your reply anyway :) @David